# Laravel 5.2 Route Automatically redirect to "Refresh" Route on Server

Tags: routes, refresh, url-routing, laravel-5

http://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/1290235/e0da843f1ce459a30871c7c2ee26810b

http://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/1290232/f29ed69ef7e4a872c993662f88bb5928

The actual issue is in laravel 5.2 then "" this route is working fine. But when I uploaded this project on server online, this Route is automatically redirect to the ""
other routes are working fine.

Please help me to solve this. What is the problem.

Comment: Please post your code. For better understanding.

Comment: to help you we need your code , man please edit post and add your code